# Feed Me 'Calling unknown method' error

Tags: plugin-feedme

I've used Feed Me many times with no issues. However this time I'm running into issues with a very simple XML feed to update existing entries. When I check Feed Me's logs I see:

```
Calling unknown method: craft\console\Request::getParam() - Component.php: 300
```

I've tried running different tests, changing different fields, different sections etc... Always the same error. Not sure what's going on here. Anyone else run into this? Any help very much appreciated.

- Craft 3.7.48
- Feed Me 4.5.3
- PHP 8.0.21
- MySQL 5.7.33

Comment: Are just using the generic XML feed type? That error suggests a console request is trying to call getParam() which is invalid in a Console request. If you are doing something custom you can check if it's a console request and bypass that logic with something like `!Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsConsoleRequest()`

Comment: Just your basic XML feed I'm afraid. No frills.